# scssphp cannot import file.sass

Tags: sass

I am using "scssphp" library to compile sass files. I have multiple files with **"sass"** extension for example `test.sass` I am unable to compile it.

```
$scss = new Compiler();
echo $scss->compile('@import "test";');
//OR
echo $scss->compile('@import "test.sass";');
```

In above example if I change `test.sass` to `test.scss` it works flawlessly.

Please note, I am using bulma framework and all its sass files are with .sass extension. Is there a workaround to compile sass files just like scss files please

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing following

1. Used [`sass-convert`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert) and run command `(sass-convert -R ./ -F sass -T scss)` which helped me to convert all .sass files (bulma files) into .scss
2. Used [`sass-bundle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle) to create single scss file for bulma.
3. Used `scssphp` to run my final compile with other scss files and my variables.